# Design pattern for page logging

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am creating my website using spring.
I am thinking of implementing a good design pattern for logging data for each page hit.
These logs are very crucial for identifying the user pattern etc. 
There is a set of common parameters that I need to log for each page hit but apart from common parameters, each page have a different parameter to be logged.

I am thinking of what design pattern should I implement for achieving this?

I thought of using stratergy Pattern but I didn't actually like it much.

For eg. parameter A,B,C are common and in addition to these my 
   Search page logs F,G,H
   Browse page logs I,J,K

```
public interface CommonParameters {
    void logCommonParameters(String a, String b, String c);
}

public interface SearPageParameters inherits CommonParameters {
    void logSearchParameters(String F, String G, String H);
}

public interface BrowsePageParameters inherits CommonParameters {
    void logBrowsePageParameters(String I, String J, String K);
}

public class LogHelper {
    CommonParameters commonParameters;
}
```

But this requires classes to implement BrowsePageParameters so that I can instantiate it in LogHelper.
I don't want to create a class for each Page.
Any suggestions on what design pattern should I follow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read about some `interceptor` :) and put some into configuration of your `web.xml`. 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Your code will be much more cleaner and solution more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response, the links you shared help me as where should I log, but I am still unclear about what structure or design pattern should I follow so that plugging in new pages, or new parameters for a page is easy and consistent.

Comment: You can get request parameters from `HttpServletRequest` object. There is no need to introduce any special pattern it is already implemented. But when it comes to logging I will advice you `visitor` pattern. http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor

Comment: It is not only request parameters, but data that we get from downstream services as well.
Thanks, I am taking a look at the pattern.

Comment: As you can see `interceptor` is working on enter and exit of your request handling, so you can also get some data from `HttpServletResponse ` :)

Comment: You can also go with `AOP` approach but it might be harder. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944259/logging-using-aop

Comment: Just join stackoverflow, don't have enough reputation to upvote.